# GhostScript and PDF/A?

Tags: ghostscript, pdfa

I am using GhostScript but it generates incorrect PDF/A files.

How do I generate correct PDF/A files from a PostScript file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question doesn't have much information to help in formulating an answer. Current versions of Ghostscript are known to create PDF/A files which validate with a range of PDF/A validation tools. That said, these tools vary significantly, and occasionally a new one crops up which checks something that previous ones have not, and this gets fixed.

You don't say what version of Ghostscript you are using, the command line invocation (which is absolutely essential for PDF/A generation) or the operating system, nor do you tell us what is wrong with teh PDF/A files you are generating. Have you read the documentation supplied with Ghostscript on how to produce PDF/A ? In a full release of Ghostscript the documentation for this can be found in :

gs/doc/Ps2pdf.htm#PDFA

However some Linux distributions do not supply the Ghostscript documentation, so it can also be found at:

http://www.ghostscript.com/Documentation.html

Specifically for your case :

http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.04/Ps2pdf.htm#PDFA

Notice that this is for the current release 9.04. There have since been some changes relating to PDF/A which will be in the next release.

Comment: i upgraded to latest. now it works well without problems. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Do you have any details about fixes in the next (post 9.04) release with regards to PDF/A processing.